# How to use SKS multivalve adapter with dunlop valve?

Tags: valves

I have the [SKS Rennkompressor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0019HKEV8) with the [multi valve head](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003FVCWI4). How do I probably use the head with a dunlop valve? I cannot get the dunlop valve fixed with the multi valve head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DE Valve, or Dunlop Valve, is the same size and thread as the presta valve, at the tip.  However, the length of the valve where it is the same diameter as presta valve is much shorter.

Pump heads which rely on the compression of an o-ring to attach to the valve, especially with multi-valve heads, often do not find enough surface area on the DE valve to stay attached.

There is no good solution to this problem, aside from changing the pump head.